# Syntax error with generic type P in calculation in SELECT

Tags: abap

I have a method in a class that has a parameter type P, but I am getting the following syntax error when I try to activate:

> No generically typed variables (like I_DISCOUNT) can be used in expressions.

The code is:

```
  METHODS ceil_floor_abs IMPORTING i_discount TYPE p .

  METHOD ceil_floor_abs.
    SELECT carrid, connid, paymentsum, paymentsum * @i_discount AS disc_payment,
           ceil( paymentsum * @i_discount ) AS ceil_payment,
           floor(  paymentsum * @i_discount ) AS floor_payment,
           abs( paymentsum ) AS abs_payment
        INTO TABLE @DATA(it_sflight4) UP TO 10 ROWS
      FROM sflight.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Try giving it a specific size: `DATA price TYPE p LENGTH 16 DECIMALS 2.`

Comment: Adras thanks, but is there any way during the method definition? Or how to pass a parameter like this in the method?

Comment: Define a local lv_discount  with the mentioned type, fill it with the content of i_discount, and use it in the SELECT

Comment: Thanks Andras. This way came in my mind also and I fix the problem. But as I am not an expert, I was wondering if there was another way to do it.

Comment: @András it's worth an answer

Comment: Declaring a parameter or a field symbol with type P is considered a generic type because it can have any number of digits/decimals. If you use `TYPES` to declare a standalone type, you have to indicate the number of digits/decimals which makes it complete (i.e. not generic), and you may use it to type the parameter so that to use it directly in the SELECT. But if you really want a generic parameter (any numeric type for instance), then you must do as explained by András (note: the type which may contain all numbers is `decfloat34`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Define a local intermediate variable

Define `lv_discount` with `TYPE p LENGTH 16 DECIMALS 2` (or whatever you need), fill it with the content of `i_discount`, and use it in the SELECT:

```
  METHODS ceil_floor_abs IMPORTING i_discount TYPE p .

  DATA: lv_discount TYPE p LENGTH 16 DECIMALS 2.

  lv_discount = i_discount.

  METHOD ceil_floor_abs.
    SELECT carrid, connid, paymentsum, paymentsum * @lv_discount AS disc_payment,
           ceil( paymentsum * @lv_discount ) AS ceil_payment,
           floor(  paymentsum * @lv_discount ) AS floor_payment,
           abs( paymentsum ) AS abs_payment
        INTO TABLE @DATA(it_sflight4) UP TO 10 ROWS
      FROM sflight.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

Answer (score 1):

No generic types are allowed in SQL expression.You need to do it by `Internal Table`.

```
SELECT carrid, connid, paymentsum, paymentsum AS disc_payment,
     paymentsum AS ceil_payment,
     paymentsum  AS floor_payment,
     abs( paymentsum )  AS abs_payment
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_sflight4) UP TO 10 ROWS
FROM sflight.

DATA:
      lt_sflight_ceil_floor_abs LIKE lt_sflight4.

lt_sflight_ceil_floor_abs =  VALUE #( FOR sflight IN lt_sflight4 (
                                                       carrid        =  sflight-carrid
                                                       connid        =  sflight-connid
                                                       paymentsum    =  sflight-paymentsum
                                                       disc_payment  =  sflight-paymentsum * i_discount
                                                       ceil_payment  =  ceil( sflight-paymentsum * i_discount )
                                                       floor_payment =  floor(  sflight-paymentsum * i_discount )
                                                       abs_payment   =  sflight-abs_payment ) ).
```